# Redirect Express route to a different route while passing data in between

Tags: node.js, express

I have a web page where a user can select their subscription type as such:

[image]

The goal is for the end-user to click on **Buy Subscription**, which should take the subscription type and price, and get that price reflected in /payment page.

Currently, I've set up a router to handle this POST request and return a JSON object back to the console for testing purposes which seems to work and return a JSON object as a response reflecting the price.

I'm using the fetch API to send the dataset values (via POST) of each button:

```
// Send a POST request to veridy the subscription ID and get its price
const purchaseSubscription = async (subscription) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/subscription/purchaseSub/${subscription}`, {
        method: "POST"
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            // Price received back from the backend
            console.log(response.json());
        }
     })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

// Get the value of each subscription type using their dataset omitted...
```

This gets sent to the backend with a value of 1, 6 or 12 respectively and is compared against a function that parses these numbers and returns their price equivalent.

My express router for subscriptions:

```
// Verification of 1, 6 and 12 in getSubscriptionPrice() omitted...
subscriptionRouter.post("/purchaseSub/:subType", (req, res) => {
    const subscriptionType = req.params.subType;
    if (subscriptionType == 1 || subscriptionType == 6 || subscriptionType == 12) {
        const price = getSubscriptionPrice(subscriptionType);
        res.json({price: price});
    } else {
        res.status(400).send();
    }
});
```

The thing is, while the price gets sent back in the console, I want to take this price and redirect the user to /payments and display the price there inside an element.

I don't want to send this value as a parameter, I want it to be sent as either body data or some other way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass it as query param `?price=16` or URL param `/payments/16`, I can suggest two other ways.

1. Save the price in `localStorage` and retrieve it on the `/payments` page

```js
// set value
localStorage.setItem('price', price);

// get value
const price = localStorage.getItem('price');
```

OR...

2. Render the `/payments` page from the Node/Express backend directly and use some template engine (like EJS or Pug) to render the price directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the payment price in local storage and redirect to the '/payment' page, and you can retrieve local storage from payment's page and display the pr

PurchaseSubscription Function :

```
const purchaseSubscription = async (subscription) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/subscription/purchaseSub/${subscription}`, {
        method: "POST"
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            // Price received back from the backend
            console.log(response.json());
            const { price } = response.json()
            localStorage.setItem('price', price);

            window.location.replace("/payment");

        }
     })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Payments Page :

```
const price = localStorage.getItem('price');
```